# AWS ECS Custom RunTask Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am using AWS ECS and invoking tasks via the AWS SDK RunTask function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html

I am pulling messages from an SQS queue in these tasks and want to send these messages as string back in the RunTask response. Does anyone know how I could add this in the response, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. RunTask exits as soon as it asks ECS to run a task. It doesn't sit and wait for a task to complete before returning a response. It doesn't even wait for the task to start running. Also, there's no way to "send a response" back from the docker container running inside ECS.

Are you sure AWS Lambda isn't a better fit for your use case? If not, then you will need to have your docker application running in ECS push your response somewhere else, like to SQS, SNS, SES, etc.

Comment: Thanks for getting back again Mark. What im doing can be done with Lambda easier but I am experimenting with Fargate and EC2 via ECS. Using something like SQS is definitely something that will work, but I was wondering do you think it would be possible with EC2 to have my docker set some kind of env variable with data and task arn in the host instance, have the ec2 instance listen in for requests with a task arn and then have the ec2 return the env variable as a response to the request. I was thinking this might work for EC2, for fargate I was probably going to look into step function tokens.

Comment: No, docker containers can't set environment variables on the host instance. Step Functions is the correct method to do this sort of thing with ECS (Fargate or EC2).